# react-bootstrap dropdowns no longer working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've had an app working for a while that utilizes react-bootstrap in the browser, running on react 15. For no discernible reason (to me anyway) react-bootstrap dropdowns have inexplicably ceased to function. There is not associated error in the console, they just do nothing on click. As far as I can tell I have them setup correctly. My code is essentially just:

```
<DropdownButton title="title" id="id" onSelect={function}>
    <MenuItem eventKey={1}>1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey={2}>2</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

which is identical to their examples and was working last time I checked. I have no idea why it isn't working and with no error there is no way to debug so I'm freakin perplexed.

See live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/oxee3L35/

Comment: It's working just fine, you need to change the css, just add right version of bootstrap and it will work. Try adding this one:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: well thanks, thats ridiculous. "the right version of bootstrap" how did you figure that out? in the react-bootstrap docs the link provided is bootstrap/latest/ there is no mention of incompatibility @het0